# Why is the date retrieval wrong by years? (strtotime)

Tags: php, mysqli, strtotime

I am creating a membership site whereas when they register, a date timestamp is created and stored in the mysql table. This is the code in the registration form.

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exp_date" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($exp_date = (date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+365 day"))), ENT_QUOTES);  ?>">
```

The result saved in the table is 2019-04-09.
When I use this code to check and be sure the date is displayed correctly, this is the result.

```
$UserRegDate = $row_User['exp_date'];
$MembershipEnds = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($UserRegDate)). " + 1 day"));

<div><?php $currentDate = date("Y-m-d");// current date?>
```

Hello "; ?>

The display reads like this...  Hello Your expiration date is: Wednesday 31st of December 1969

So it is stored correctly in the database from the registration form, but retrieved as 1969 instead of 2019. Could this be a server issue, and perhaps a php.ini setting?

I'm new but learning php and thank you in advance! Totally puzzled over this!

Comment: My code didn't show up correctly in my question. The following is the registration form insert code.  <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="exp_date" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($exp_date = (date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+365 day"))), ENT_QUOTES);  ?>">

Comment: all of the entries doesn't work? or just this one? code seem to work fine if input is [correct](https://3v4l.org/5NoY0)

Comment: This is the test code to retrieve the date from the database... $UserRegDate = $row_User['exp_date'];         $MembershipEnds = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($UserRegDate)). " + 1 day"));       <a>Hello <?php echo "Your expiration date is: ".date('l dS \o\f F Y', $UserRegDate)."<br>"; ?></a>                                                                                           The result in 1969 instead of 2019.

Comment: please could you post table value

Comment: Field       |     Type            | Coalation
   id                int(11)
 user_name   varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci
 user_pass   varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci
 user_email  varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci
 exp_date    varchar(78)  latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: I also tried saving it to unix timestamp format where is is stored as 1554899548 in the exp_date column and it still displays as 1969-12-31 19:00:00 ...... If I go to online converter it converts fine. So this leads me to believe it is a server issue. I am hosting at fatcow...

Comment: All of the attempted code has resulted with a 1969 year instead of 2018 or 2019. Perhaps it is the format of mysql database? Except that is is stored correctly there but displayed incorrectly on the php page.